# Url Rewrite: how to set .hatccess for "static" dynamic url and dynamic url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've made several attempts without success.
This is what i want to do for what i mean with "static dynamic url":

```
index.php?content=authors   => /compositori/
index.php?content=albums    => /dischi/
```

The query string variable value "authors" needs to become "compositori", i've tried with this but nothing:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^compositori/$ index.php?content=authors - [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

And this is for dynamic urls:

```
index.php?content=author&c=nome-compositore => /nome-compositore/
index.php?content=author&c=nome-compositore&action=view-bio => /nome-compositore/biografia/
index.php?content=author&c=nome-compositore&action=view-albums  => /nome-compositore/dischi/
index.php?content=author&c=nome-compositore&action=view-album&a=nome-disco  => /nome-compositore/nome-disco/
```

Then i want to redirect this url "index.php?content=index" to the home page without any query string parameter and nothing after .com, index.php?content=index => www.mydomain.com

For all this rules i need also to make them work on subfolder with htaccess positioned in this subfolder, for example mydomain.com/test/. Tried with RewriteBase but nothing :/

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
Now i have these rules thanks to David:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /subfolder/index.php?content=index [L]
RewriteRule ^contatti/$ /subfolder/index.php?content=contacts [L]
RewriteRule ^compositori/$ /subfolder/index.php?content=authors [L]
RewriteRule ^dischi/$ /subfolder/index.php?content=albums [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/biografia/$ /subfolder/index.php?content=author&c=$1&action=view-bio [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/dischi/$ /subfolder/index.php?content=author&c=$1&action=view-albums [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/$ /subfolder/index.php?content=author&c=$1&action=view-album&a=$2 [L]
```

But i noticed that if i put in url the non rewritten query string (index.php?content=authors) it loads content but remain with the non formatted string and not redirect to rewritten url. I've tried to put [R=301,L] but nothing to do. This is my last issue.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RewriteRule ^compositori/$ index.php?content=authors - [R=301,L]`

This is invalid for two reasons: you have three areas of the rule rather than the required two (extra `-` at the end) and you are lacking a leading slash. You also have it set to redirect (`R=301`), but probably just want to rewrite. This should be changed to:

`RewriteRule ^compositori/$ /index.php?content=authors [L]`

Once you get that working, the remaining conversions you posted should work similarly.

> Then i want to redirect this url "index.php?content=index" to the home
>   page without any query string parameter and nothing after .com,
>   index.php?content=index => www.mydomain.com

You are using the term "redirect", but based on the direction of the arrows in your previous examples, you may mean "rewrite" in the opposite direction, so here's the answer both ways:

To have the user enter `www.mydomain.com` and have the server actually load `index.php?content=index` (what I think you really mean):

`RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.php?content=index [L]`

To truly have `index.php?content=index` redirect to `www.mydomain.com`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^content=index$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.mydomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

EDIT: Regarding your final question about redirecting the full path with query string to the "pretty" URL, you would implement what I wrote immediately above (RewriteCond + RewriteRule) for each of the specific rewrites and you would place the rules above your existing (new) rules. In other words:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^content=index$
RewriteRule ^subfolder/index.php$ http://www.mydomain.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^content=contacts$
RewriteRule ^subfolder/index.php$ http://www.mydomain.com/contatti/ [R=301,L]

... repeat for remaining rules

RewriteRule ^/?$ /subfolder/index.php?content=index [L]
RewriteRule ^contatti/?$ /subfolder/index.php?content=contacts [L]

... repeat for remaining rules
```

This causes each full URL with query string to be redirected to the pretty URL, then the pretty URL is rewritten silently to the full URL. A couple of notes about the new rules you listed above:

First, you added a /subfolder to each rule which wasn't present in your original question. Just in case you want the rule to apply with or without the subfolder, you would add that part in parentheses with a question mark at the end like:

```
RewriteRule ^(subfolder/)?index.php$ http://www.mydomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Also, the new rules you wrote require the matching path to end with a slash. Since a directory path ending with or without a slash is equivalent, you should make that optional by adding a question mark after the slash like I did in the example above (`contatti/?`):

Comment: Thank you very much! I have one last question, see edited post.

Comment: Updated with response to your new question.

Comment: I was unable to do the redirect via htaccess but I eventually resolved through php. However, next week I move the project from the subfolder to the root and I will make new attempts. Thanks again David (: